# Selenium Error No signature of method: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.find_element_by_class_name() is applicable for argument

Tags: selenium, missingmethodexception

I would like to find my TextField in selenium, but I don't know how to do exactly(I use selenium for the first time).

I tried the following option to try it but nothing worked

1. `driver.find_element_by_name(Token).send_keys(abcdefghijklm)`
2. `driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid').send_keys("asbfsbgkf")`
3. `driver.find_element_by_cssSelector("input.form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid[placeholder='Token string']")`
4. `driver.findElementByCSSSelector("input.form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid[placeholder='Token string']")`
5. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'][@type='text']").send_keys("asbfsbgkf")`

Someone, please help me here. I would really appreciate it.

Here is the HTML: (Highlighted the one I need to search - "Second Value" Input)

`

```html
<html lang="en" class="gr__xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx">
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true"><!--  <g:savetophone id="savetomobile_tag" --><!--  onsuccess="successHandler"--><!--onfailure="failureHandler" size="small" theme="light" ></g:savetomobile>--><app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.4.6"><div _ngcontent-c0="" class="container-fluid">
  <nav _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button _ngcontent-c0="" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li _ngcontent-c0="" class="nav-item active">
          POC Tester
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="col-12">
      <app-user-input _ngcontent-c0=""><div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Please provide the following information</h3>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group-mt-2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
              <div class="d-inline-block dropdown" ngbdropdown="">
        <button aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbdropdowntoggle="" aria-expanded="false">environment</button>
        <div aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" ngbdropdownmenu="" class="dropdown-menu">
          <!----><button class="dropdown-item">status</button><button class="dropdown-item">status</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      </span>
      <input aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="URL" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="https://something.something.com" type="text">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group-mt-2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
              <div class="d-inline-block dropdown" ngbdropdown="">
        <button aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbdropdowntoggle="" aria-expanded="false">Enjoy button</button>
        <div aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" ngbdropdownmenu="" class="dropdown-menu">
          <!----><button class="dropdown-item">Enjoy button</button><button class="dropdown-item">Offers &amp; Notifications</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      </span>
      <input aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="URL" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="https://something.somewhere.com" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mt-2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn  btn-secondary" type="button">First value</button>
      </span>
      <input aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="URL" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="test value" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mt-2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn  btn-secondary" type="button">Second Value</button>
      </span>
      **<input aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="URL" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="user value" type="text">**
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="input-group mt-2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn  btn-secondary" type="button">third value</button>
      </span>
      <input aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="URL" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="test user" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Generate value</button>
    </div>
    <!----><div class="mt-4">
      press:
      
      
      <div id="location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ngb-progressbar type="success">
    <div class="progress">
      <div aria-valuemin="0" role="progress" class="progress bg-success" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
        <!---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngb-progressbar>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mt-5">
    <p>content:</p>
    <textarea class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" rows="20"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</app-user-input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></app-root><script type="text/javascript" src="inline.0c00000000000000ca85.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="000000000000000015b.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.0000000000000fc0000.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.00000000fgf000000gdf.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.cf3000000000000eb000a.bundle.js"></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpaths were returning lists in most cases. Since we know we are looking for the second input element we can just take the second result from the list with the following code:

```
second_input_xpath = "//div[@class='input-group-mt-2'][2]//input"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(second_input_xpath ).send_keys("asbfsbgkf")
```

With regard to the main error in the title it looks like you have not initialised your Chrome webdriver correctly. I would suggest looking [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) at the selenium docs.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I was busy with some other things. Here is the code which I use to initialize chrome browser. It is opening the URL but then it is throwing this error  -------------          import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver


//Initiate WebDriver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com.au/")

Comment: @user8472243 I'm not sure what your error is from the comment. Can you update your question with a code snippet and the point at which you are getting an error. Also the language you are coding in would be useful to Tag on the question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all the inputs field having same class name.So in order to make it unique try this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'])[n]").send_keys("value")

where n=1,2,3...n
```

PS n=1 for the first element.Kindly let me know if this helps.